# Hide div when clicking outside div and siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide the div "auto" ONLY when you click outside of that div.

At the minute if you click on "more-stuff" it will hide the div because you are not clicking on "auto". So i guess my question is how to include the siblings in the IF statement (there could be many divs inside by the way but "more-stuff" is just an example).

```
 <div id="auto">
   <div id="more-stuff">
      HIDE ALSO WHEN YOU CLICK IN HERE!
   </div>
 </div>

 jQuery(document).click(function(e) {
     if( e.target.id != 'auto') { // Hide when click outside of layer
         jQuery("#auto").hide();
     }
 });
```

I expect clicking on sibling elements to NOT close the div also

Comment: Need to see more HTML.  What siblings? Are they siblings to `#more-stuff`? So, you only want `#more-stuff` to hide when you click the parent of `#auto` ? Which one is the div that should close? Sorry, it's just not clear what you want to happen, and when. Please edit your question and clarify these details. *Thanks!*

Answer (score 4):

You can use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to check if the event target have parent with id `#auto` or not.

Demo:

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest("#auto").length) {
      $('#auto').hide();
    }
 });
```

```css
#auto {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="auto">
   <div id="more-stuff">
      HIDE ALSO WHEN YOU CLICK IN HERE!
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Precisely what I needed thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="auto">
   Will Not Hide here
   <div id="more-stuff">
      NOT HIDE ALSO WHEN YOU CLICK IN HERE!
   </div>
</div>

<script>
   $(document).click(function(e){
     if ($(e.target).is('#auto,#more-stuff, #more-stuff *')) {
       return;
     }

     $('#auto').hide();
   });
</script>
```